# TypeScript isObject & isNullOrUndefined deprecated angular

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading from angular 7 to angular 10 and using TypeScript 4 or above. I started get warning deprecation of `isObject()` and `isNullOrUndefined()` functions when I run `ng lint`

###### warnings

```
isNullOrUndefined is deprecated: since v4.0.0 - use `value === null || value === undefined` instead.
isObject is deprecated: since v4.0.0 - use `value !== null && typeof value === 'object'` instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating a my own `utils.ts` file in my project `utils/utils.ts`. I exported following two methods.

###### File utils/utils.ts

```
/**
 * custom function to support deprecated function isNullOrUndefined
 * @param value any
 * @returns boolean
 */
export function isNullOrUndefined(value: any) {
    return value === null || value === undefined;
}

/**
 * custom function to supported deprecated function isObject
 * @param value any
 * @returns boolean
 */
export function isObject(value: any) {
    return value !== null && typeof value === 'object';
}
```

Then I updated all imports of `isNullOrUndefined` and `isObject`

###### From:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined, isObject } from 'util';
```

###### To:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined, isObject } from '@common/lib/utils/utils';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `isNullOrUndefined()` function, I'd rather turn the logic around and use a [type-predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```js
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined | null): value is T {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}
function bar(foo: string | undefined | null) {
  if (!isDefined(foo)) {
    return undefined;  
  }
  // note, that typescript now knows that foo must be a string
  return foo.split('.');
}
```

see [Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhTAHgQwLYAcA29oDMD2ATtABYAuZ6AzgFzDBVnIDGA1vgG7yG6b4DuAOmb5UwAI4BXeIwCW+AHZVgANgAcAZgCcAVgCMAFj3AyAT3QzmhWejIBaWVXwAjAFbxm9xwsmY+hSQUAE3hcWQV4ILsQ9EIPZDJIu2QFAHNfZEIoWGAoXEDPeQVoRwARUPDIgB4AFQA+AAoOZExpGmga6AAfaECQsIig7ugfPwBKdubWnEcO6ABvbOg4sklCYqnpaABCAF5d3uCKwegAMlPoTZw9g9HMAG4oAF88grIi6GdMhoJ8dsZrGlhn1jpFhncxgslrJcNAGtsyqCgj98PgxpDFjBoNiVmtiiCBpF7tili8sfQRvhEgAaaBkEgJOnmSzWWyU-jQVgKARUOkMsh4VHQVCSRifHDIaAA8KpJa49aC-CCKhYWRkBoAckEGrGj0gZKgoAgMDgRFkqXCLWgAGUAPLQFJUfjcdrkSi0eiMFjsLg8PhCERiZCqTS6QwAJmAegADEYVEZsiBcpB8gpCooSlQAHK+TC2wgAVSOhORV3aKVMGKWOPgqwVV2g+1uue6PQbTcO-UqQT1BpTbw+X0I4ZRfylZEBqWBxe74NzVaxMLhjhzfnzRa7g1H6KhWJrdfxM8GeuxZOxFO5iXa9JwgfQsmwCEIhCIpG48FpzniopwZgsVCsGwBTkPxoCCfAZEpAUuQEPlGV+TMwKROVazxRVlVVdUtR1XsoCAA)